# text file editing in command line

Tags: command-line

I have a big text file like this:

```
@HWI-ST132_459:6:2208:20745:200766#AGTTCC/1
CCCAGGGGGTTGCTAGGTTGAAAGAGAAGAACTAAGCTTAAA
+
ca^WcZX[D_T]GQI^]^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
@HWI-ST132_459:6:2208:21328:200860#AGTTCC/1
CATTTTGGTGGGTTGTGGTTTTGGGGGGTTTGTTGTTGGGTT
+
]TPKODYF[TSHWUQRRGZV`N_Y`c\abc]]D_BBBBBVVF
```

in which every 4 lines belongs the same ID. the ID line starts with @.
in all cases the 3rd line is +. 
I want to split my file into different files based on the the first 3 characters of 2nd line (which is between the line that starts with `@` and the line that starts +). for example if the above example is a file, I want to divide it into 2 files in the following order:
since the first 3 characters of 2nd line of ID1 is `"CCC"`, the first ID (starting with `@`) and related lines would be one separate file and since the 2nd line of the 2nd ID starts with `"CAT"` the 2nd ID and corresponding lines would be in another file.

I do know how to do that in command line(shell in the linux). do you know?

here is the expected outputs:
file1:

```
@HWI-ST132_459:6:2208:20745:200766#AGTTCC/1
CCCAGGGGGTTGCTAGGTTGAAAGAGAAGAACTAAGCT
+
ca^WcZX[D_T]GQI^]^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

file2:

@HWI-ST132_459:6:2208:21328:200860#AGTTCC/1
CATTTTGGTGGGTTGTGGTTTTGGGGGGTTTGTTGTTG
+
]TPKODYF[TSHWUQRRGZV`N_Y`c\abc]]D_BBBB
```

Comment: "Command line" is not a programming language, it's a broad term that refers to an interactive prompt. What tools do you know or are you prepared to use?

Comment: No, I don't know. I could figure it out though.

Comment: @tadman: by command line I meant shell in the linux

Comment: When you say "I do know how to do that", do you mean you do *not* know how to do that?

Comment: I mean I am not familiar with command line in linux

Answer (score 1):

We like genetic data :-)

I'm guessing unix/bash? You really aught to have tagged it...

You could do something like

```
grep -hom1 '^[^@+]..' filename

-o only echos the matching chars
-m1 only prints one match
-h shouldn't be necessary - it hides the filename
```

Try it first to see if it what you want!

Over a number of files you could try:

```
for f in *.ext
do
    cp $f $f.`grep -hom1 '^[^@+]..' $f`
done
```

Try it on a few files first to see if it what you want! Also put echo before cp to do a dry run!

Comment: it does not return what I want.

Answer (score 0):

*If* (and this is potentially a big if) your input data does not contain any occurrences of the `@` character except at the start of your id lines, you could simply do:

```
awk '{file=substr($2,1,3); if(file) print "@"$0 > file;}' RS=@ input-file
```

Comment: Hi William, the first line starts with @. that is correct, but I divide every 4 lines based on the 1st characters of 2 line (which is after the line starting with@)

Comment: Yes, this script divides the input into files named after the 1st 3 characters of the second line of each record.

Comment: It requires that there be no extraneous `@` symbols, and no additional whitespace.